# Multiple data sources in grafana dashboard

Tags: postgresql, prometheus, grafana

I am using two data sources: `Prometheus` and `Postgres`.

The common field from both data sources is an instance IP.
Generally, we install `node exporter` in every instance, and using Prometheus we will pull metrics. We also store some other details of servers
in the Postgres data sources.

Few servers we didn't install node exporter(we didn't install it because those are not reachable) but we stored those servers' data in Postgres.

I want to add a filter in the Grafana dashboard such that there should be three options: All, Reachable, and Unreachable.

1. If I click All, every instance that is there in the database should appear.
2. If I click Reachable, only reachable servers should appear.
3. If I click Unreachable, only unreachable servers should appear.

But I can get Reachable and Unreachable servers/instances using metrics "UP" from Prometheus Query Language.

But If I click the ALL option I am not getting all servers, because on some servers where I didn't install node exporter those servers I
am not able to populate the table.

Do I need to do anything while using two Data Sources? Any transformations I need to do in Grafana so that it can be achievable?

Thanks in advance

Thanks & regards,
Bharath Kumar.

Comment: I would recommend to rephrase your questions and add more details. It is really not clear what you have and what do you want to have

Comment: @JanGaraj, Hii... I added some more details. Hope you understand now. If not, pls let me know I will add the missing things.

Comment: Nope, is your filter "Grafana dashboard variable"? How do you query both datasources? You mentioned only prometheus metric up, but how your Postgres metrics looks like is unknown. Please provide reproducible example.

Comment: yes, the filter is a grafana dashboard variable. I am querying Prometheus data source and using outer join we can merge both data sources. I am not getting the instances that were not present in the Prometheus, like can we get this using any transformations or any other methods?